# Apply flex property to React mapped items

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, reactjs, flexbox

I have an array of items that I'm mapping over and would like to style them as flex wrap items so they end up in a row. However, I've tried multiple ways to go about this but the items remain listed in one column.

This is the result I'm going for: https://www.nike.com/w/mens-training-gym-shoes-58jtoznik1zy7ok

```
            
         <div>
            <h3>All Shoes ({allShoes.length})</h3>
            {allShoes.map(item => {
                return (
                <section key={item.id} style={{display: 'flex'}}>
                    <div>
                        <img src={item.image} alt={item.name}/>
                        <p>{item.name}</p>
                        <p>{item.subTitle}</p>
                        <p>{item.price}</p>
                    </div>
                    
                </section>)
            })}
        </div>
```

Comment: You need to show the complete CSS. Or is it only having inline CSS?

Comment: Just inline CSS for now for testing purposes. This is the only styling I've added so far. Don't want to add more until I get this part right.

Comment: You are only applying the 'flex' to the first child div. Either remove that wrapper div or add 'flex' to the div inside of section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating several `section` elements, each containing just one `div`.

To get the divs displayed in a row, create one `section` and put multiple `div`s inside it. Something like this:

```html
<div>
  <h3>All Shoes</h3>
  <section style="display: flex">
    {allShoes.map(item => {
      return (
        <div key={item.id}>
          <img src={item.image} alt={item.name}/>
          <p>{item.name}</p>
          <p>{item.subTitle}</p>
          <p>{item.price}</p>
        </div>)
    })}
  </section>
</div>
```

Here's what that looks like as rendered HTML:

```css
section {
  background-color: #a0a0a0;
}
section:before {
  content: "section";
  padding: 1rem;
  color: #606060;
}
section div {
  margin: 4px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: white;
}
section div p {
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>All Shoes</h3>
  
  <!-- a single section with flex -->
  <section style="display: flex;">
  
    <!-- containing multiple divs -->
    <div>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140" />
      <p>item.name</p>
      <p>item.subTitle</p>
      <p>item.price</p>
    </div>

    <div>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140" />
      <p>item.name</p>
      <p>item.subTitle</p>
      <p>item.price</p>
    </div>

    <div>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140" />
      <p>item.name</p>
      <p>item.subTitle</p>
      <p>item.price</p>
    </div>

  </section>
</div>
```